# How to filter some particular tasks using get-scheduledTasks from task scheduler of a remote machine

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I am trying to get list of scheduled tasks from some remote machines using the `get-scheduledTasks` cmdlet. How to list those tasks and filter out only few tasks out of them and perform actions based on the presence of those tasks

Comment: Have you tried Where-Object cmdlet? With that cmdlet you can perform filtering. Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Ready' -and $_.TaskName -like '*Google*'}

Comment: Do you mean [`Get-ScheduledTask` _cmdlet_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask) or something like [`Get-ScheduledTasks` _function_](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ScheduledTasks-Get-d2207def)?

Comment: I meant get-shcheduledTasks funtion for getting remote machine tasks and filtering them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name="Start of task name or absolute name"
$servers="server01","server02","server03"

$tasks = $servers | % { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { Get-ScheduledTask | ? { $_.Name.StartsWith($name) } }
```

What you then do depends on what you want to do with those tasks.